# I am getting a System.NullReferenceException on WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress) , not sure where to get more details to find out what is wrong

Tags: c#, api, owin

I'm following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

I followed all the steps to the dot, but as soon as I start the program this line
`using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))` always produce a `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Programs.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace OwinSelfhostSample 
{ 
    public class Program 
    { 
        static void Main() 
        { 
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/"; 

            // Start OWIN host 
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress)) 
            { 
                // Create HttpClient and make a request to api/values 
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 

                var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/values").Result; 

                Console.WriteLine(response); 
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); 
                Console.ReadLine(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
 }
```

Startup.cs

```
using Owin; 
using System.Web.Http; 

namespace OwinSelfhostSample 
{ 
    public class Startup 
    { 
        // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
        // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) 
        { 
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
                name: "DefaultApi", 
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
            ); 

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

ValuesController.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace OwinSelfhostSample 
{ 
    public class ValuesController : ApiController 
    { 
        // GET api/values 
        public IEnumerable<string> Get() 
        { 
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" }; 
        } 

        // GET api/values/5 
        public string Get(int id) 
        { 
            return "value"; 
        } 

        // POST api/values 
        public void Post([FromBody]string value) 
        { 
        } 

        // PUT api/values/5 
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value) 
        { 
        } 

        // DELETE api/values/5 
        public void Delete(int id) 
        { 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and saw the expected output from the tutorial. Have you checked that you're using the right .NET version? Maybe add the contents of `App.config` and `package.config` to the question?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?